# How may I start a VirtualBox VM and issue a command to that VM to launch a specific program?

Tags: virtualbox

Given a fresh VM. Can I set up a desktop shortcut or CLI to start virtualbox and inside the VM launch a program?

Ideally, I may have to set up a function in .bashrc

```
throwaway() {
    VBoxManage startvm "Stock-RHEL-7" --type headless
    ssh -X user@local-ip-address '$1'
}
```

That'd be called via

```
$ throwaway firefox
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

I need to do this to test desktop applications (over local X forwarding) on different distros of Ubuntu and RHEL. Some Q&A. Sometimes to sandbox packages we're evaluating. I don't want to pollute my base install of LTS/16.

(While I'm aware of X11 as an attack vector. We know the app sources. They are trusted.)

Comment: You probably (not sure, not using VirtualBox) can have a command to directly boot a VM on your host computer and you can configure your VM guest OS to auto-start a specific application on boot. I doubt that it will be possible to trigger launching a specific application inside the VM from the host in any other way though.

Comment: Yep, virtualbox. I updated my question a bit hopefully expanding what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I personally can't think of a cleaner way than what you describe using ssh, but I'm not too experienced with those tools, so I'm probably not too helpful.

Comment: @ByteCommander I still appreciate any guidance. Even your comments here have been helpful so far. Much appreciation.